# General formula for the denominator of Taylor expansion of $\sqrt{1-x}$

Tags: taylor-expansion, radicals

The Taylor expansion of the square root $\sqrt{1-x}$ is

$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^n (-1)^n \binom{1/2}{n}
,$$

the first terms being

$$
1-\frac x 2 -\frac{x^2}{8}-\frac{x^3}{16}-\frac{5x^4}{128}-\ldots
$$

Is there a general formula for the $n^{\rm th}$ denominator? It is obvious that it will be of the form $2^m$, but it is not obvious what $m$ should be.

Comment: Hint:
\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-4x}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n} x^n.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: The denominator is the largest power of $2^n$ that divides $(2 n)!$. There are many ways to make this variously explicit: See http://oeis.org/A046161

Comment: This is hardly an answer, but if you take $\sqrt{1-4x}$, then all coefficients are integral, indeed all but the constant coefficient are even. And those in degree $2^n$ are indivisible by $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple OEIS search for $\,1, 2, 8, 16, 128, 256\,$ turns up the
[OEIS sequence A046161](http://oeis.org/A046161)
from which the comment

> Denominator of coefficient of $x^n$ in $(1+x)^{k/2}$ or $(1-x)^{k/2}$ for any odd integer $k$.

is applicable to your question with $k=1.$ A formula in the entry implies that $\, a(n) = 2^{b(n)} \,$ where $\, b(n)=A005187(n)\,$ and
[OEIS sequence A005187](http://oeis.org/A005187) has the formula $\, b(n) = \sum_{k\ge 0} \lfloor n/2^k \rfloor. \,$

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that writing 
$$\binom{1/2}{n}$$ is the correct notation. If the power is a fraction then we just use the same idea but we write: 
\begin{align}
\binom{1/2}{k}
&=\frac{\frac12(\frac12-1)(\frac12-2)\cdots(\frac12-k+1)}{k!}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2^kk!}1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2k-3)\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{2^kk!}\frac{(2k-2)!}{2^{k-1}(k-1)!}\\
&=\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k2^{2k-1}}\binom{2k-2}{k-1}
\end{align}
This could give you a general expression.

Comment: Good answer but I think saying "[not] the correct notation" is slightly misleading. The notation is still correct, even if it isn't as informative as the form with $k2^{2k-1}$.